# EventHandler in a separate class

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

The following code allows to switch between two scenes.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class EventHandlersExample extends Application {

  Stage window;
  Scene scene1, scene2;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      window = primaryStage;

      //Button 1
      Label label1 = new Label("Welcome to the first scene!");
      Button button1 = new Button("Go to scene 2");

      button1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));

      //Textfield
      TextField tf1 = new TextField();

      //Layout 1 - children laid out in vertical column
      VBox layout1 = new VBox(20);
      layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);
      scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 200, 200);

      //Button 2
      Button button2 = new Button("Go back to scene 1");
      button2.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));

      //Layout 2
      StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
      layout2.getChildren().add(button2);
      scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 600, 300);

      //Display scene 1 at first
      window.setScene(scene1);
      window.show();
  }
}
```

However, I'd rather see my EventHandler in a separate class, like this:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class EventHandlersExample extends Application {

  Stage window;
  Scene scene1, scene2;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      window = primaryStage;

      //Button 1
      Label label1 = new Label("Welcome to the first scene!");
      Button button1 = new Button("Go to scene 2");

      //button1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));
      Button1Handler button1handler = new Button1Handler();
      button1.setOnAction(button1handler);

      //Textfield
      TextField tf1 = new TextField();

      //Layout 1 - children laid out in vertical column
      VBox layout1 = new VBox(20);
      layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);
      scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 200, 200);

      //Button 2
      Button button2 = new Button("Go back to scene 1");
      button2.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));

      //Layout 2
      StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
      layout2.getChildren().add(button2);
      scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 600, 300);

      //Display scene 1 at first
      window.setScene(scene1);
      window.show();
  }
}

class Button1Handler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
      @Override
      public void handle (ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("OK button clicked");
      window.setScene(scene2);  
    }
  }
```

Yet, the reference to window in the `EventHandlersExample`-Class does not work.

The same problem occurs (of course) when I try to `textfield.getText()` from a textfield in the `EventHandlersExample`-Class.

How can I fix this?---Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *The same problem occurs* : which error? :)

Comment: First, you should use lambda if possible. Second, to fix your issue quickly, you can move the `}` under `window.show()` to the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're encapsulating the event-handling logic in a separate class, you need to somehow pass references of the parent window and the scene to the handler. A convenient way to do this is to inject the dependencies through the constructor:

```
class Button1Handler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private final Stage window;
    private final Scene scene;

    public Button1Handler (Stage window, Scene scene) {
        this.window = window;
        this.scene = scene;
    }

     @Override
     public void handle (ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("OK button clicked");
         window.setScene(scene);  
    }
}
```

You'd then create the handler with `new Button1Handler(window, scene2)`.

Comment: Huh. There seemed to be a edit without a notification by stackoverflow...

Comment: Thanks, Mick. The codes runs. Clicking the Ok-button does result in printing "OK button clicked". However, the switch to scene2 does not yet work. Any idea?

Comment: How are you using this? Have you initialized `scene2` properly?

Comment: I use it exactly as in my code above except for the changes you suggested.

Comment: Try initializing `scene2` _before_ the `new Button1Handler(window, scene2)` line. You're currently passing in a `null` reference to the handler and this won't update later on due to Java being pass-by-value.

Comment: That did it. Thanks, Mick!